# How RSpec load a Model with conditional validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a Model with 3 migrations:

1. creates the db table, *(production code, already exists)*
2. inserts initial records into the table, *(production code, already exists)*
3. add new **"___type"** column to the table *(new migration)*

After that, I added a validation to the Model to force the presence of the new **"___type"** attribute.

The 2. migration failed because the create method wanted to validate the __type attribute but at that time this column didn't exist.

To avoid that I added the `if column_names.include?(:__type)` clause to the migration so all migrations passed.

But after that RSpec validation fails:

```rb
class MyModel

validates :__type, presence: true if column_names.include?(:__type)
```

RSpec spec:

```
it { should validate_presence_of(:__type) }
```

RSpec error:

"MyModel did not properly validate that :__type cannot be empty/falsy.
         After setting :__type to ‹nil›, the matcher expected the
         MyModel to be invalid, but it was valid instead."

**Note:**

I intentionally use standard `if` keyword instead of symbol `if:` because for the 2. migration needs to evaluate this clause when the code itself is loaded.
So when I run the migration it doesn't require "__type" column, but when I run the rails server it already exists.

How can I test the presence of **"___type"** attribute?

Comment: Have you run migrations against the test environment?

Comment: Yes, of course:
```rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test```

Comment: I see... Have you tried it in development? In the console, or whatever. Seems like `::column_names` returns an array containing strings and you are checking a symbol.

Comment: The "__type" attribute is available. The validation is not avaliable. The column_names includes "__type" both in rails console and when I print before :each test case.